# What are all these weird escape characters and how can I parse / ignore them?

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to get the classic Zork running with a little Python script, and I've made some good progress with Frotz. Here's my code:

```
import pexpect

dos = pexpect.spawn('frotz -dp /home/theuser/zork1/DATA/ZORK1.DAT')

dos.expect(">")
print(dos.before.decode('ascii'))
```

And then I run the script like:

```
python test.py > output.txt
```

However, the output looks like:

```
u_setup.blorb_file /home/theuser/zork1/DATA/ZORK1.blb
u_setup.blorb_name ZORK1.blb
^[[?1049h^[[1;24r^[(B^[[m^[[4l^[[?7h^[[?1h^[=^[[H^[[2J^[(B^[[0;7m West of House                                    Score: 0        Moves: 0      ^[[14;1H^[(B^[[mZORK I: The Great Underground Empire
^[[15dCopyright (c) 1981, 1982, 1983 Infocom, Inc. All rights reserved.
^[[16dZORK is a registered trademark of Infocom, Inc.
^[[17dRevision 88 / Serial number 840726
^[[19dWest of House
^[[20dYou are standing in an open field west of a white house, with a boarded front
^[[21ddoor.
^[[22dThere is a small mailbox here.
^[[24d
```

What are all those escape sequences (^[[15d, ^[[20d, ^[[24d, etc) called? I think they have something to do with cursor/console information because when I run the script without redirecting the output to a file they don't appear (and the terminal moves around a bit).

All I want is the output from the Zork commands: IE "You are standing in an open field west of a white house, with a boarded front door. There is a small mailbox here."

How can I strip those (control sequences?) with Python? Is there a regex that I can use for every case?

Comment: go look up ANSI.

Comment: If you're absolutely sold on the regex option, [this should work](https://regex101.com/r/SstgJz/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are command sequences intended to be interpreted by the terminal driver. Since you aren't using a terminal driver, you need to tell `frotz` to not expect one.

```
oldterm = os.environ['TERM']
os.environ['TERM'] = 'dummy'
dos = pexpect.spawn('frotz ...')
os.environ['TERM'] = oldterm
```